# Spring Boot sperate @Configurations for multiple application contexts

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I'd like to run one spring boot application but have it listen on multiple ports.

The aim is to be able to let an Apache forward multiple (sub-) domains to the spring boot application (Tomcat) on different ports. Example:

```
         example.com/** -> PORT 8080
  client.example.com/** -> PORT 8090
employee.example.com/** -> PORT 8100
```

As far as I understood from several threads on SO, I'm best off launching multiple `@SpringBootApplication` Annotated classes from one main class, right? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25870132/1510659)

What I didn't grasp yet, is how to configure each one of those applications separately.

Let's say I have launched these three Applications as shown in the linked post above:

```
MainExampleApplication
ClientExampleApplication
EmployeeExampleApplication
```

Now, for example, I want to have separate Spring Security `@Configuration` classes for each of these Applications, as well as `@RequestMappings` which might have the same value (e.g. "/").

How do I tell the `@Configuration` or `@Controller` classes which Application they are assigned to?

Or are there properties that can to be passed to the applications on startup to specify which resources are responsible for the context?

I hope I'm not going in a totally wrong direction here. I do have experience with Spring MVC and have configured some rather simplistic Spring applications - but not with multiple contexts. I'd be really glad if someone could lead me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in iamiddy's answer and xeon's comment, I used Spring Profiles for that. I provided the SpringApplicationBuilder with a profile for each of my application contexts on startup and used the `@Profile("some_profile")` on the `@Components` that should only be available to some of the contexts.

Comment: Could you consider using [Spring Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Profiles` it's a great spring feature, loads only beans associted with the profile.
Once that's done start your applications **N** times with different `port` and `profile` arguments

Ex: Here is how you would start the first one, do it for the rest to your **N**

`java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production1 -Dserver.port=9000 app.jar`

Comment: That does look promising. I'll try it out later in the day and will report :)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to report... This use of profiles was in fact the solution for me!