# How to develop a Maven Multi-module application using the Spring Boot framework

Tags: java, spring, maven, modularity, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a maven multi-module Java project that runs perfectly, until I try to include the Spring Boot framework. The main module, called **core**, gets called OK, but all the rest are unable to implement the interface I declared in **Core.java**.

This error gets thrown:

```
[ERROR] /F:/mvnmodularapp/module1/src/main/java/service/impl/ModuleServiceImpl.java:[12,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Service

[ERROR] /F:/mvnmodularapp/module1/src/main/java/service/impl/ModuleServiceImpl.java:[13,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

---

**The project structure:**

```
mvnmodularapp/
             /pom
mvnmodularapp/core/
             /src
             /target/core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
mvnmodularapp/module1
             /src
             /target/module1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

---

**THe file/directory structure:**

```
core/src/java/service/
                    Service.java

core/src/java/service/impl
                        CoreServiceImpl.java

module1/src/java/service/impl
                        ModuleServiceImpl.java
```

---

**Service.java**

```
public interface Service {

    String getName();
}
```

**CoreServiceImpl.java** in **core**

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Hi. You called me from ServiceImpl in Core";
    }
}
```

**ModuleServiceImpl.java** in **module1**

```
@Service
public class ModuleServiceImpl implements Service {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Hi. You called me from ModuleServiceImpl in module1, but I can\'t pick up right now. Sorry";
    }
}
```

---

**THE POMS**

**mvnmodularapp pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mvnmodularapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvnmodularapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>module1</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

**core pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>mvnmodularapp</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mvnmodularapp</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Core</name>
    <description>SudenGut application</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <start-class>main</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.24</tomcat.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--- this will not be enough to provide a cool app :) -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**module1 pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>mvnmodularapp</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mvnmodularapp</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <start-class>baseview.impl.BaseViewImpl.ModuleServiceImpl</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.24</tomcat.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--- this will not be enough to provide a cool app :) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mvnmodularapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: `F:/mvnmodularapp/module1/src/main/java/service/impl/Service.java:[13,5] ` in compilation error and the class edited in the question in this package is `ServiceImpl`. It is not consistent.

Comment: Sorry. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies between modules are correctly declared but you have one thing that is not configured as required.
I am not sure it will solve your problem but it could.

You declare in each module :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It should be required only for the module which bootstraps the Spring Boot application.
If you want have multiple web applications in the same Spring Boot container, you could [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868218/run-multiple-web-apps-in-one-spring-boot-container).

As you say that it works before adding Spring Boot I think that the problem should be solved with previous recommandation.
But if it is not enough, below are other guessworks which could be the cause of the compilation error. I rely on this error message :

> [ERROR]
>   /F:/mvnmodularapp/module1/src/main/java/service/impl/ModuleServiceImpl.java:[12,30]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: class Service

- The `Service` class is not imported in `ModuleServiceImpl`.
  If I rely on what you write in your question, you should add :
  `import service.Service` in the imports of `ModuleServiceImpl`.
- The core module doesn't create a JAR with the `service.Service` class.
  So, importing it doesn't solve the problem of the `module1` module.
  You should perform a `mvn clean install` from the core module and check that the jar contains the compiled class : `service.Service` in the good package.

Comment: actually you can use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent to yours app parent module and benefit from from dependency management from spring's parent module.

Comment: @StasKolodyuk  indeed it is enough. Thank you for the feedback. I updated my answer consequently.